# java lwjgl getting Could not create context (WGL_ARB_create_context)

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am working on an lwjgl project that has the following code:

```
public class DisplayManager {

    private static final int WIDTH = 1280;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 720;
    private static final int FPS_CAP = 120;

    public static void createDisplay() {
        ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);

        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
        } catch (LWJGLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(DisplayManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        GL11.glViewport(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    }

    public static void updateDisplay() {
        Display.sync(FPS_CAP);
        Display.update();
    }

    public static void closeDisplay() {
        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error message:

> org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not create context (WGL_ARB_create_context)
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.nCreate(Native Method)
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.create(WindowsContextImplementation.java:50)
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.(ContextGL.java:132)
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:850)
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:797)
>       at javaapplication15.DisplayManager.createDisplay(DisplayManager.java:34)
>       at javaapplication15.engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:21)
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.getCapabilities(GLContext.java:124)
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glViewport(GL11.java:3261)
>       at javaapplication15.DisplayManager.createDisplay(DisplayManager.java:41)
>       at javaapplication15.engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:21)
>   Java Result: 1

Comment: Looks like it might be telling you that your system does not support OpenGL 3.2. Are you sure that it does?

Comment: Intel Pentium with HD Graphics, I searched the web and it looks like it doesn't support it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It may not answer your question, but my solution may be a help to others.
If your laptop has integrated graphics card and additional more powerful graphics card it is likely that you will get this error. It is because your created program uses integrated graphics card, which does not support OpenGL 3.2. However if you will switch to your second, more powerful, graphics card your program will work fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please, read the question again, carefully. When read the answer again, carefully. When think again.

Answer (score 0):

Could not create context (WGL_ARB_create_context)

I know that the question is not years ago but in case it helps

You solved the same problem and solved it by deleting the enter parameters of `create ()`

`Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);`  //before

Change for:

```
 Display.create();
```

and run

Comment: but how we can manage them new PixelFormat(), attribs